# Making a scrollbar act on a certain div object

Tags: css, html, scroll

I can't find a good way to word this so it's been hard finding this on the internet I'm sorry, but I'm trying to make the main browser scrollbar act on a certain div object only.

Here is a link:

http://gigadra.in/

It would make the middle content scroll down as I plan to have the max height set to the browser window height.

Does anyone know what property I could use to start working on this?

Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at using `position: fixed;` in CSS. You can make the sidebars and footer fixed.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Comment: And you don't need to set the maximum height of your page. Set the height of your header and footer - the middle will take the remaining space.